# Hex value in string format to Hex numerical for sorting

Tags: java, string, hex

I am working on a project where the hexidecimal lines of code are read from a file.  Then, I need to store all the data in a structure, of which I chose a map.  The key to my map is the address number for the instruction, which is the first four characters of the hex string.  I have already separated the strings as I need.

Getting to the point:

I need to convert a string such as adr = "001B" to the numeric hex value 001B.  Everything else I have seen is for converting a string such as "ABC" to hex by each individual character.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("001B", 16);
```

See the documentation of [`Integer.parseInt(String s,
                           int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) as well.